# JAXB Schema design, having enum dynamic value

Tags: xsd, jaxb, schema

I have following schema

```
<xs:simpleType name="enumType">    
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">    
        <xs:enumeration value="STRING_ONE"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="STRING_TWO"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

As long as i get a known string, I can swithc and it to my jaxbobject which expects a `enumType` object. But what if i don't know this string ? is there a way to handle it based on JAXB Schema ? I know based on enum its not possible.

---

**Edit**: Trying to make it more clear

Wit the given Schema design, my JAXBObject, which accepts `enumType` as a parameter, can only have 2 input values i.e. STRING_ONE or STRING_TWO which will be converted to XML as part of marshalling.

The question is, that what if, I want to handle a situation through my schema design that if I can have an object of `enumType` then good otherwise I can give an XML to JAXBObject instead of `enumType` and it still parses it.

Comment: Are you looking to change the property from an enum to a string so that you can handle more than the values defined in the XML schema?

Comment: This is the last approach and yes, it will definitely work. But i was wondering if there is an option by which we can specifiy a field in schema which can handle both the enumeration and enumeration **base** value (string in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the XSD point of view, it sounds like you want to be able to write

```
<xs:simpleType name="soft-enumeration">
  <xs:union>
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="STRING_ONE"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="STRING_TWO"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:union memberTypes="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This type includes the enumeration you describe, but it then unions it with xs:string, so as to accept other values as well.  If your schema interface gives you access to information about which member type of the union was used, then you can use that information to treat instances of STRING_ONE and STRING_TWO differently from other strings.

I have no idea whether jaxb does anything useful with this idiom, however; there you're on your own.